# Cucumber No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-glue'

Tags: spring, scope, cucumber, bdd

I have `No Scope registered for scope name 'cucumber-glue'` error while running Cucumber (6.1.1) BDD tests with Spring

My configuration file

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:/application-context-bdd.xml"})
@CucumberContextConfiguration
public class Configuration {

}
```

My test file

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {
        "json:target/cucumber-json-report.json" },
        glue = {"xx/java/bdd/configuration", "xx/java/bdd/stepdefs", "xx/java/bdd/steps"},
        features = "classpath:features",
        publish = false
)
public class TestBDD {
}
```

My application context file, where my `cucumber-glue` bean is declared.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   
    <bean name="todoRepository" class="xx.java.core.domain.mock.TodoRepositoryMock" scope="cucumber-glue"/>

    <bean name="todoService" class="xx.java.core.domain.todolist.service.impl.TodoListServiceImpl">
        <constructor-arg ref="todoRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="todoStep" class="xx.java.bdd.steps.TodoStep">
        <constructor-arg ref="todoService"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="xxx.java.bdd.stepdefs.TodoStepDefinition"> <!-- Not needed since @M.P. Korstanje reply -->
        <constructor-arg ref="todoStep"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

any idea ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is to declare all `todoRepository`  depending beans in `cucumber-glue` scope

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   
    <bean name="todoRepository" class="xx.java.core.domain.mock.TodoRepositoryMock" scope="cucumber-glue"/>

    <bean name="todoService" class="xx.java.core.domain.todolist.service.impl.TodoListServiceImpl" scope="cucumber-glue">
        <constructor-arg ref="todoRepository"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="todoStep" class="xx.java.bdd.steps.TodoStep" scope="cucumber-glue">
        <constructor-arg ref="todoService"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct scope is `cucumber-glue` but it only exists when a scenario is active. By defining a bean in the `xml` it will be created when the application starts, before any scenario has started.

You don't need to define `TodoStepDefinition` as bean though. Cucumber will created it as needed.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/spring#sharing-state

Comment: My apologises the scope is ```cucumbre-glue``` I did this mistake when I wrote the question. You are right, StepDefintion does not seem to be needed. I re-edited my question with more details. I still have the error